# Square coefficient matrix, matrix transpose, and solvability of the corresponding system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $n \geq 2$. I would like to prove that, for every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}$, there is a $b \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ such that
$Ax = b$ is unsolvable if and only if $A^{\top}x = 0$ has infinitely many solutions.

After some contemplates, I only proved a related version of the above assertion, namely: For every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}$, there is a $b \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ such that $Ax = b$ is unsolvable if and only if $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions. Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{F}$, since $Ax = 0$ has infinitely many solutions iff the induced linear transformation $T_{A}$ is not injective so that $T_{A}$ is not bijective and hence $T_{A}(x) = b$ has no solution for some $b \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$.

However, so far I have still not seen how to take the transpose into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the problem ? Assume that $A\in M_{n,m}(F)$.

There is $b$ s.t. $Ax=b$ has no solutions iff $A$ is not surjective iff $rank(A)<n$.

$A^Tx=0$ has at least $2$ solutions iff $A^T$ is not injective iff $rank(A^T)<n$ iff $rank(A)<n$.